# Get Admin rights on a not-yet-liked Open Graph page

Tags: facebook, admin, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to enable admin rights on an Open Graph page before anyone likes it ?

I'm trying to create an event related to that "next-to-be-created" page, when I publish the article page, without having to wait for someone to like my page.

Users will be able to create those pages, so I can't Like them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be alright if you're defining your admins using `fb:app_id`.

If you're using `fb:admins = "<UID>"`, then we require the user to interact with the page so that people can't start randomly adding them as admins.

Comment: by your first sentence you mean by defining the admins in the App settings (roles section), right?

Comment: The right meta tag is : **fb:app_id**

One thing I have to do before actually using the page is "Linting" the page with the Debugger.

So, before creating my event I have to curl _http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=xxxx_

Comment: @ifaour He means by using fb:app_id meta tag in the Open Graph Page, and setting admin rights in the App Settings